# Why are user created namespaces not being recognized by Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

For some reason when I create a new namespace in Visual Studio 2008 its not being recognized. I'm using asp.net mvc, I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Has anyone come across this before?...and how do you fix it?
Also is there a way to force Visual Studio to maybe re-examine new namespaces?

**Answer:**
I figured out the problem...[check it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146745/why-are-user-created-namespaces-not-being-recognized-by-visual-studio-2008#146883).

Comment: What do you mean by not recognized? I'm creating new namespaces every day and never ran into issues with VS 2008.

Comment: It was working fine and than 1 day I did a compile and it stopped recognizing any new namespaces. Its really weird. I was thinking maybe it had something to do with asp.net mvc, but that could have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Did you do a clean recompile? :)

Comment: It just happens in this 1 project that I'm working in.

Comment: How do you do a clean recompile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure how this happened but the build property for this class file was set to "content". The compiler didn't see the new namespace. As soon as I set it to "compile", it worked fine.

Weird!

Answer (score 0):

Questions:
Is the namespace and class thats not being picked up in the same project or is it referenced?
Is this a vb or a c# project? - I cant remember which way round (think its c#) but one of them defaults the root namespace to the project name. You can run into problems or get a confusing namespace e.g MyProject.MyProject if you create one at the same level of the root namespace.

Couple of things to try:

Press ctrl alt b to rebuild the project does it pick up the namespace? 
Add a new method to an existing class that is working - is this picked up?

Try creating a completley different namespace is this picked up e.g.

namespace StackOverflow.Test
{

}

Finally have seen studio not pick up new namespaces and methods when its not compiling properly. This can be due to NTFS permissions and read only permissions. Check the build date of the dll. You can also try clearing ASP.net temporary files.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure  your class is either private or public because when we add class to project it by default private and private is not accessible in other project